# Use Excel Function (Search/OR/IF) to categorize products

Tags: excel

I want to use a Function in Excel to categorize the products from a product list; in order to make it happen, I have used the **search** to look for the keywords of each category then use **OR** to take into account different situation and **if** to differentiate the outcome.

The function I have written is like this:

```
=IF(OR(find("DVD";A14)>0;find("VCD";A14)>0;find("MEDIA";A14)>0;find("Radio";A14)>0;find("sound";A14)>0;find("mp3";A14)>0;find("youtube";A14)>0;find("voice";A14)>0;find("audio";A14)>0;find("player";A14)>0;find("music";A14)>0);"Media & sound";IF(OR(find("Chat";A14)>0;find("Communication";A14)>0;find("Messenger";A14)>0;find("Message";A14)>0;);"Chat";IF(OR(find("image";A14)>0;find("photo";A14)>0;find("retouch";A14)>0;find("picture";A14)>0);"Photo & Retouch";IF(OR(find("disk";A14)>0;find("clean";A14)>0;find("uninstall";A14)>0;find("speed";A14)>0;);"Computer clean & uninstallers";IF(OR(find("design";A14)>0;find("3d";A14)>0;find("graphic";A14)>0;find("animation";A14)>0);"Design & Graphics";IF(OR(find("anti";A14)>0;find("virus";A14)>0;find("secur";A14)>0);"Security";IF(OR(find("language";A14)>0;find("education";A14)>0;find("learn";A14)>0);"Education";"Others")))))))
```

However, the outcome is error.
Does anyone have idea about why there would be an error ?
Also, if you have a better idea to do the categorization, it will also be appreciated !!

Comment: Find is not like Instr in vba, if the value is not found then it returns an error not `0`  and you cannot equate an error.  You will need to wrap each of your Finds in an IFERROR: `IFERROR(find("DVD";A14),0)` do that for every one,  then look into array formulas that will allow you to list all the lookups and return the proper value with a much shorter formula.

Comment: @jsheeran Thanks a lot!!